# Modify ComboBox display in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to modify the display of a (non-editable) `JComboBox` in such a fashion that the currently selected entry has some extra text in the edit field (*not* the dropdown list, though).

Something like this:

[image: Mockup]

My first guess was to override the ComboBox’ model so that `getSelectedItem` returns a wrapper object modifying the display:

```
petList.setModel(new ComboBoxModel() {
    private Object selected;

    public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
        selected = anItem;
    }

    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return new ActiveComboItem(selected);
    }

    // … The rest of the methods are straightforward.
});
```

Where `ActiveComboItem` looks as follows:

```
static class ActiveComboItem {
    private final Object item;

    public ActiveComboItem(Object item) { this.item = item; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return item == null ? other == null : item.equals(other);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("Animal: %s", item); }
}
```

Indeed, this works as far as modifying the display goes. Unfortunately, the current entry is no longer marked as active:

[image: Wrong display]

(Note the missing check mark … or however the selection is displayed by your OS.)

Further inspection shows that the model’s `getElementAt` method is called with an index of `-1` every time the user selects a new item in the box. This is *only* the case when using the modified selected item. When the model’s `getSelectedItem` method returns the plain object without wrapper, then the selected item is marked as selected in the dropdown box, and `getElementAt` is *not* called with an argument of `-1`.

Apparently, the ComboBox is comparing each item in turn to the currently active item but, despite my overriding the `equals` method, it finds no match. **How can I fix this?**

(Full, compilable code for this problem [**at gist.github.com**](https://gist.github.com/1279388))

Comment: just for the record: that implementation of ComboBoxModel is invalid as it doesn't fire a ListModelEvent on setSelectedItem

Comment: @kleopatra Good to know. FWIW, the code was just a minimal try to get this working in the first place, before making it proper.

Comment: not firing is a common reason for misbehaviour :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a custom ListCellRenderer. The following works:

```
    final JComboBox animalCombo = new JComboBox(animals);
    animalCombo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list, Object value, final int index, final boolean isSelected,
                final boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (index == -1) {
                value = "Animal: " + value;
            }

            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    });
```

index is -1 when the value its painting is the one that's not in the dropdown.

For future reference, when you just want to change how something is displayed in Swing, you never want to modify the backing model. Every component has a renderer, and generally you just need to slightly modify the default one.

Comment: +1 - Don't modify the model to make the UI change. Instead, extend the renderer to add the additional pieces.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t quite work. The JComboBox doesn’t seem to use the `DefaultListCellRenderer` by default: using the above code, the display of the currently selected item differs from the normal rendering (at least on OS X). /EDIT: It’s `com.apple.laf.AquaComboBoxRender`. Still, this works with only tiny modifications.

Comment: Addition to my previos comment: instead of using `super.getListCellRendererComponent`, store the previously used renderer before setting the new one, and use its implementation.

Comment: @Konrad: Yeah, that's actually a better idea to support default renderers in different look and feels.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you Konrad Rudolph. I extended a JComboBox to use a custom renderer and have spent hours trying to get the background of the combobox to look right. Without saving off the render ahead of time, I was just calling super.getListCellRendererComponent and ending up with a white background when using windows LaF. Even oracle's custom combo demo has a white back ground when you set the LaF to windows because it doesn't respect the UI LaF.

Answer (score -1):

create `JTextField` and `JButton` with `Icon`, for `JButton` implements `ButtonModel`, by overriding its methods `isRollover(), isPressed(), isArmed()`

don't extract `Icon` from `JComboBox`, paint own Triangle, then `JButton` with `Icon` will be `Look and Feel` and `Native OS` resist, for nicer output implements `JButton#setRolloverIcon()` too

create a `JPopup` or `JWindow`, put here `JScrollPane`, display this Container from `model.isPressed()` or `isArmed`

now you have two choises

1) create `JList` that contains `JCheckBox` (remove rectangle from JCheckBox)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class CheckList {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Create a list containing CheckListItem's
        JList list = new JList(new CheckListItem[]{
                    new CheckListItem("apple"),
                    new CheckListItem("orange"),
                    new CheckListItem("mango"),
                    new CheckListItem("paw paw"),
                    new CheckListItem("banana")});
        // Use a CheckListRenderer (see below) to renderer list cells
        list.setCellRenderer(new CheckListRenderer());
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {// Add a mouse listener to handle changing selection

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
                JList list = (JList) event.getSource();
                int index = list.locationToIndex(event.getPoint());// Get index of item clicked
                CheckListItem item = (CheckListItem) list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                item.setSelected(!item.isSelected()); // Toggle selected state
                list.repaint(list.getCellBounds(index, index));// Repaint cell
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

// Represents items in the list that can be selected
class CheckListItem {

    private String label;
    private boolean isSelected = false;

    public CheckListItem(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
}

// Handles rendering cells in the list using a check box
class CheckListRenderer extends JCheckBox implements ListCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {
        setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        setSelected(((CheckListItem) value).isSelected());
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
        setText(value.toString());
        return this;
    }
}
```

.

2) or implements [ListSelectionModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620579/individual-and-not-continuous-jtables-cell-selection) and add/remove `Icon` on MouseClick

hide `JPopup` or `JWindow` from `MouseListener` Event

Comment: ehhh ... and this random code is related to OPs problem in that... ?