# Panels inside JPanel with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I was trying to create UI similar to TweetDeck in Java.

I guess the columns are equivalent to panels and also the timeline shown is also equivalent to panels. So I guess there are many panels.

I was trying to make such UI, but failed. I am not much into Java Swing so I tried to create it using Netbeans framework.

Is there any simple Java code that can solve some of my problems?

I guess everything should be dynamic here.

If I am wrong about panels here (because I guess too many panels can create problems) please guide me.

Comment: *"I am not much into java swings so I tried to create it using netbeans framework."* A) It is (1) 'Java' (2) 'Swing' & (3) 'NetBeans' B) Until you understand 1 & 2 - 3 won't help. C) What is 'TweetDeck'?  Care to share an URL or (better) screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three choices:

- Easiest and more conformable is to use lots of [JPanels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) (that each contain [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)) laid by [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) inside [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- put `JPanels` (that each contain `JComponents`) is a [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- put overview `JPanels` (that each contain `JComponents`) in a [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to implement every column as a JList instead since it looks like you want your columns to have scrollable content. See [How to Use Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: +1 for `JList`, which I tend to overlook; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620579/individual-and-not-continuous-jtables-cell-selection/7620726#7620726).