# Show ScrollBars in FlowLayout only when necessary

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I will rephrase my question:**

How to prevent Java ScrollBar from being enabled in FlowLayout when there is enough space to show all items by warping them.

[image: example]**

Here a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

Note that scrollbar is disabled when it is not necessary.
[image]

And when you resize the window scrollbar should appear if some items are out the viewplane
[image]

P.S. I am aware of things called documentation and web.

Comment: *"What I currently have is:"* Uncompilable code snippets.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"However compared to WPF, Java doesn't show and hide scrollbars when necessary"*  Java must be broken, use WPF for this one.

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: You may be looking for [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/).

Comment: This looks like it is addressing the problem I am having. The only thing I do not understand is why FlowLayout doesn't do it by default?

Comment: I have to agree with @camickr, `FlowLayout` is a strange animal! In particular "When the components are wrapped to a new row, the preferred size doesn’t change so you never see the components on the extra row."

Comment: It's a reach, but you may be able to leverage the `HORIZONTAL_WRAP` mode of `JList`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620579/individual-and-not-continuous-jtables-cell-selection/7620726#7620726).

Comment: @trashgod, post your comment about Wrap Layout as an answer, to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated screen shots suggest that you may be looking for [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/), which "extends the `FlowLayout`" in a way that "will result in synchronizing the preferred size of the container with the layout of the container." See also [*Creating a Custom Layout Manager*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).

Comment: Unfortunately for me, that doesn't look very GPL friendly as there's no license, so that's no good for my project :-(

Comment: Ah, found the relevant comment. "Rob Camick said January 12, 2012 at 10:46 am You can use/modify the code however you wish." Hurrah.

Comment: It was such a royal pain removing the null character from the middle of the file that I created a copy at https://github.com/timabell/WrapLayout to save everyone the hassle.

Comment: I am a little intrigued how it can be an intermittent issue but hey. I tried chromium, wget and curl and they all resulted in the corrupt file. Some editors seem to cope better than others with the null.

Answer (score 3):

The default scroll bar policy is *as needed*, but I remember having to account for the `FlowLayout` gaps to get an even number initially. If you stretch this example out, you'll see the horizontal scroll bar disappear.

Update: It doesn't really fix your problem, but it shows how I implemented `Scrollable`. I wanted to get rid of `setPreferredSize()`, even tho' the image is just a placeholder. The [Wrap Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141035/show-scrollbars-in-flowlayout-only-when-necessary) article talks about why `FlowLayout` works the way it does.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ImageScrollTest extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

    private static final int N = 8;
    private static final int W = 120;
    private static final int H = 100;
    private final FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
    private final int hGap = layout.getHgap();
    private final int vGap = layout.getVgap();
    private final Dimension size;

    // Show n of N images in a Scrollable FlowLayout
    public ImageScrollTest(int n) {
        setLayout(layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this.add(new ImagePanel());
        }
        size = new Dimension(n * W + (n + 1) * hGap, H + 2 * vGap);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(
        Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return getIncrement(orientation);
    }

    @Override
    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(
        Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
        return getIncrement(orientation);
    }

    private int getIncrement(int orientation) {
        if (orientation == JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL) {
            return W + hGap;
        } else {
            return H + vGap;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
        return false;
    }

    private static class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final Random rnd = new Random();
        private Color color = new Color(rnd.nextInt());

        public ImagePanel() {
            this.setBackground(color);
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(W, H);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageScrollTest ist = new ImageScrollTest(N / 2);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ist);
        sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        f.add(sp);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good example +1. That is exactly what I have. The problem is that I want the wrap panel to wrap items as long as there is some available space and if there is none, only the show the scroll bars.

Comment: no, you do not have to "take gaps into account" - that's the job of the layoutManager. Do not use setXXSize - ever. Instead, let your panel/s return reasonable calculated size hints in their respective getXXSize method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi

Comment: It is possibly true about setXXSize, but it is not a point of the discussion.

Comment: @Vitalij: Now that I see your update, `WrapLayout` looks like the right answer.

Comment: @kleopatra: You're right; I was lazy on the preferred size. I ysed the gaps to implement `Scrollable` in my update. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud specify to the scrollPane when you want the scrollBars to apprear (possible in both horizontal and vertical direction):

```
myScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

There is also: `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` and `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` if you need that anytime soon.

EDIT: For more information, and exactly my answer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: I have already tried this. For some reasons Java doesn't hide scroolbar in FlowLayout

Comment: Well, is the width of all the content larger than the window? Post some code, we can't help you more by guessing...

Comment: What I am getting is exactly as posted by @Catalina Island

Comment: Nope it doesn't it shows the scrollbar all the time. But what I am trying to achieve is to show a scrollbar only when it is needed. And by as needed, I mean that if wrap panel can wrap items instead of showing a scrollbar it should do so.

Comment: OK, so please post some code, probably the JFrame creation, so we can see where the problem is...