# Java Swing : Make a Scrollable list of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

so i'm making an interface using NetBeans, and here's what I want to do :

I've created a JPanel class, wich shows some informations on objects (labels, texFields and buttons).
I want to add several panels like the one above, into a same JScrollPane (to look like a list of independant Panels).

I can't use JList, because I don't want to list just the "toString" of my panels,
I've look this :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer
But I don't think this can help me (this explain how to put icons into a cellRenderer, but i'd like to add directly a Panel into a vertical List of other panels)...

Comment: Add a `JScrollPane` to you form, add a `JPanel` to the scroll pane.  You can now treat this panel as any normal container, change it's layout, add other components to it. You might like to take a look at [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: But how can I put Panels into je ScrollPane one above the other ?

Comment: Use a `GridLayout` on the "view", set to have 0 rows and 1 column.  The add any new `JPanel`s you want to the `JPanel` which is acting as the view for the scroll pane

Comment: Oh yeah ok, I didn't understand the fact that I needed to put an other JPanel into my ScrollPane.

Works good, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8154052/261156) lets you scroll little thumbnail images, but the `ImagePanel` could have components. It uses `FlowLayout` for a horizontal layout, but `GridLayout(0, 1)` would work for a vertical layout.

Comment: There are some related examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15961412/230513).