# Why do getWidth() and getHeight() return 0 before paintComponent() is called?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

> *Edit:* **I have solved the underlying problem.** I used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to solve the issue. My [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615957/when-does-a-jtabbedpane-component-get-its-size) provides more information for those who are interested.

I have a GUI that displays an image on a `JPanel` in `paintComponent()` with `g.drawImage()`. I wrote a subclass of `JPanel` called `CanvasPanelView` to override `paintComponent()` and do a few other things, like set the bounds of where the image is drawn. The problem is that I need to get the JPanel's width and height and when I call `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` in the class that extends JPanel, they both return `0`.

The process starts in an action listener inner class:

```
class MenuBarFileOpenListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        File fileChooserReturnValue = view.showAndGetValueOfFileChooser();

        if (fileChooserReturnValue != null) {
            try {
                DocumentModel newDocument = new DocumentModel(ImageIO.read(fileChooserReturnValue), fileChooserReturnValue.getAbsolutePath(), fileChooserReturnValue.getName());
                model.addDocument(newDocument);
                view.addDocument(newDocument);
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, `addDocument()` is called:

```
public void addDocument(DocumentModel document) {
    menuBar_file_close.setEnabled(true);

    DocumentView newDocumentView = new DocumentView(document.getTitle(), documentsTabbedPaneCloseButtonListener);

    documentViews.add(newDocumentView); // add newDocumentView to ArrayList<DocumentView>
    newDocumentView.setDocument(document);
    documentsTabbedPane.add(newDocumentView.getCanvasPanelView());

    int newDocumentIndex = documentsTabbedPane.indexOfComponent(newDocumentView.getCanvasPanelView());

    documentsTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(newDocumentIndex, newDocumentView.getTabPanel());
    documentsTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(newDocumentIndex);
    newDocumentView.setBounds(document.getImageWidth(), document.getImageHeight());
}

public DocumentView(String title, ActionListener listener) {
    canvas = new CanvasPanelView();
    // more code...
}
```

`setBounds()` is called:

```
public void setBounds(int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    sourceX1 = 0;
    sourceY1 = 0;
    sourceX2 = imageWidth;
    sourceY2 = imageHeight;

    // some math...

    destinationX1 = 0 + xMargin;
    destinationY1 = 0 + yMargin;
    destinationX2 = drawWidth - xMargin;
    destinationY2 = drawHeight - yMargin;
}
```

`DocumentView` is a wrapper class for `CanvasPanel` and a few other things - it just groups together things that go with each open document.

Everything seems to be instantiated and used or added to the `JTabbedPane`, so I don't know why `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` return `0`. Maybe something is happening between the end of `setBounds()` and `paintComponent()`.

Why do `this.getWidth()` and `this.getHeight()` return `0`?

Comment: `getWith()` returns 0 because the component at that time *is* zero sized, but why, I'm not sure. I don't think that you've asked an answerable question yet as you may have left out too much that would be necessary for knowing why you're seeing your error as well as left in a lot of code unrelated to the problem. If you don't get a great answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Pertinent things to mention and show with your sscce include the layout of the container that holds your image displaying component and how you add the component to the container.

Comment: agreed, right, then answer could be simple

Comment: I must assume that the two answers that you've received have adequately answered your question. Best of luck.

Comment: In your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), or use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a 'setBounds', why don't you put your *documentView* inside a Panel(BorderLayout), at a position such as BorderLayout.CENTER?

Alternatively, you can set the minimum and preferred sizes of your *documentview* based on the image dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a class, `CanvasPanelView`. This class extends `JPanel`. It appears, that in your implementation of `setBounds` you make no reference to the members of `JPanel` that `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` refer to. Hence, the underlying object is of 0 height, and 0 width.

If you wish to use the `JPanel` values for height and width, then you simply need to ensure that you are assigning values to them.