# Using Swing GUI for NetBeans to Set Background of a JFrame from a Resource

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, embedded-resource

My friend and I are working together to write a Java program, and I am taking on the task of designing the GUI. Our GUI requires a background image for the JFrame, and the image needs to be able to change based on the user's actions. I have placed the images that I want to use as the background in the project as a resource, and I would like to ask for help finding the resource path, and setting the resource path as the background image in the JFrame.

I am using the Swing GUI Builder for NetBeans to design the GUI. Can someone please offer me some help? I have no experience with GUIs, and my friend has little experience with basic Java coding, so we are assigning parts based on our knowledge.

Comment: You asksed like five questions.  You need to show what you have done and the step you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you don't want to resize the images (as the frame changes), you could simply set the frames layout to `BorderLayout` and use a `JLabel` to display the images. Otherwise you will need to construct a custom component (using something like `JPanel`) and render the image yourself
2. Looking up embedded resources is a simple process of using something like `getClass().getResource(...)`, where the parameter is the path to the resource, where the root is the top level source folder in your project.

Take a look at...

- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)
- [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: See also the [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/230513) cited in the [info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the [tag:embedded-resource] tag.

Comment: @trashgod I was talking about being able to change the image that goes on the background, but centering the image is important as well for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @PWF: I wanted to get the handy [tag: embedded-resource] material on the record. In your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), or use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513).

Comment: Changing the image comes down to how you display it