# How to found center of an image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I have faced trouble how to find center of an image and write it to different image.
Situation is that I have image (for e.g. 800X500) and I need to crop exactly (50X50 or 70X70) center of it with img.getSubimage(x, y, w, h).

Sizes will be different every time for new image.

How could I calculate X and Y to get 50X50 subImage from the image center?

Thanks in advance.

img.getSubimage(x, y, w, h) - **X and Y are not coordinates of center.** 
     * @param x the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the
     *          specified rectangular region
     * @param y the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the
     *          specified rectangular region

Comment: By using basic math? Divide by 2.

Comment: Have you tried solving it on paper first? What coordinates would you use for examples you gave in your question?

Comment: See also these related thumbnail [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15961412/230513).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int bigwidth = 800;
int bigheight = 500;
int cropwidth = 70;
int cropheight = 70;
img.getSubimage((bigwidth - cropwidth) / 2, (bigheight - cropheight) / 2, cropwidth, cropheight);
```