# Painting size with swing

Tags: java, swing, size, paint

I have a problem of size ... because I set my **Jpanel**  and **JFrame** with specific size but when I draw the image is like if the window have a different size :

```
public GameView(){
    //System.out.println("hey");
    JFrame container= new JFrame("Loderunner");
    JPanel panel= (JPanel) container.getContentPane();
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(115,115));
    panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(115,115));
    panel.setLayout(null);
    setBounds(0,0,115,115);
    panel.add(this);
    setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    //requestFocus();
    //addKeyListener(new KeyHandle());
    //container.addKeyListener(new KeyHandle());
    requestFocus();
    container.setResizable(false);
    container.pack();
    container.setVisible(true);
    container.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createBufferStrategy(2);
    strategy=getBufferStrategy();
    loadLevel("livel.txt");
}
```

Here's an image of my problem:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  But in general, set a preferred size on the panel then pack the frame.

Comment: In this link there is a folder in which there are file .java e image ... you could compile the files and run the  main file                 http://ge.tt/6aRQzsq/v/0?c

Comment: At no point did I ask for, or suggest you supply, an image.  **Read the link.**  As it happens, an image for an SSCCE can be generated in a single line of code.

Comment: Oh sorry , I don't know how do all this things , so thank you  anyway....

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that 115px width is not going to fill the minimum width of the frame with decorations.  Instead do one of:

1. Widen the rendering
2. Live with a border
3. Remove the frame decorations or..
4. Use a window instead

Comment: In this link there is a folder in which there are file .java e image ... you could compile the files and run the main file      ge.tt/6aRQzsq/v/0?c

Comment: @user2695795: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. In your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).