# How can my ActionListener for a JButton access variables in another class?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am doing a slot machine for a project. I am having trouble getting my `JButton` to generate new random numbers from my `ArrayList`. I can randomize the numbers when the program starts and have an `actionlistener` set up, but it doesn't do what I need. It was merely for testing purposes.

My `Actionlistener` is in a different Java file. Everything works, I just can't figure out how to generate new randoms in the placeholder of `plc1`, `plc2`, and `plc3` when the button is clicked.

*I have just recently began to really code as about 3 weeks ago. 
No haters please, this is my first project ever.*

```
package GGCGuiLotto;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.util.Random;


public class GGCGuiLotto {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

//Arraylist of images

ImageIcon pic0 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic1.png");
ImageIcon pic1 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic2.png");
ImageIcon pic2 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic3.png");
ImageIcon pic3 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic4.png");
ImageIcon pic4 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic5.png");
ImageIcon pic5 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic6.png");
ImageIcon pic6 = new ImageIcon("pics/pic7.png");

final ArrayList<ImageIcon> slotlist = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();   
    slotlist.add(pic0);
    slotlist.add(pic1);
    slotlist.add(pic2);
    slotlist.add(pic3);
    slotlist.add(pic4);
    slotlist.add(pic5);
    slotlist.add(pic6);

    Random ran = new Random();

    int plc1 = ran.nextInt(4);
    int plc2 = ran.nextInt(4);
    int plc3 = ran.nextInt(4);

    //generates the frame and the labels are added.

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize (400,275);
    frame.setTitle("GGC Lotto Slots Rcorbin");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JPanel pnlReels = new JPanel();
    frame.add(pnlReels);

    JPanel aReel1 = new JPanel();
    aReel1.setBackground(new Color(25,25,112));
    aReel1.setBounds(15,10,100,100);

    JPanel bReel2 = new JPanel();
    bReel2.setBackground(new Color(25,25,112));
    bReel2.setBounds(145,10,100,100);

    JPanel cReel3 = new JPanel();
    cReel3.setBackground(new Color(25,25,112));
    cReel3.setBounds(275,10,100,100);   

        pnlReels.add(aReel1);
    pnlReels.add(bReel2);
    pnlReels.add(cReel3);   

    JLabel aReel1lbl = new JLabel();
    JLabel bReel2lbl = new JLabel();
    JLabel cReel3lbl = new JLabel();

    aReel1.add(aReel1lbl);
    bReel2.add(bReel2lbl);
    cReel3.add(cReel3lbl);  

    aReel1lbl.setIcon(slotlist.get(plc1));
    bReel2lbl.setIcon(slotlist.get(plc2));
    cReel3lbl.setIcon(slotlist.get(plc3));  

    //jbutton 
    JButton slotbtn1 = new JButton();
    slotbtn1.setText("GGC LOTTO Click ME");
    pnlReels.add(slotbtn1);
    slotbtn1.setBounds(145,50,100,75);
    //FirstGuiListener act = new FirstGuiListener();
    //slotbtn1.addActionListener((ActionListener) act); 

GenPLCListener genPLC = new GenPLCListener();
slotbtn1.addActionListener((genPLC));
    {}
    if (plc1 == plc2 && plc1 == plc3 && plc2 == plc3)
    {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Winner! Play Again? ","GGC Lotto Slots RCorbin ",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        //System.out.println("Winner");
    }
    else
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Winner Winner Chicken Dinner ! ");
        System.out.println("Crazy");    }

}
}
```

---

```
package GGCGuiLotto;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class GenPLCListener extends GGCGuiLotto implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("Works");

JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Choose Wisely. ","Click If you Trust!",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}
}
```

Comment: In your [sscce](http://sscce.org/), access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: I'd just like to comment that having variables named `pic1`, `pic2`, `pic3` and `plc1`, `plc2`, `plc3` is kind of confusing. You might consider not doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to `extends GGCGuiLotto` isn't going to do what you think it's supposed to, which is give you access to the *same* instance variables. So get rid of that.  Instead you can *pass-by-reference*, the current instance of `GGCGuiLotto` to your listener. And have some getters and setters to access the variables you need from the `GGCGuiLotto` class. What I mean is maybe something like this (not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish, so this is just an example).

```
public class GenPLCListener implements ActionListener {
    private GGCGuiLotto lotto;

    public GenPLCListener(GGCGuiLotto lotto) {
        this.lotto = lotto;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerfomred(ActionEvent e) {
        List<ImageIcon> slotList = lotto.getSlotList();
        Collections.shuffle(slotList);  // shuffle the list
        // do something else if need be.
    }
}
```

When you create the listener, pass `this` to it. `this` being the instance of `GGCGuiLotto`

---

**Few Side Notes**

- Swing programs aren't like console programs. You don't want to do everything inside your `main` method.  For starters, the code in your `main` method, you could put in the constructor instead. Then create an instance of `GGCGuiLotto` in the `main` method.
- Swing apps should be run on the Event Dispatch Thread. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

---

### EDIT

Maybe a more proper solution to your problem would be to have an `interface` with the `pullSlot` method that you can override in the `GGCGuiLotto` class and just pass the `interface` to the listener and call the `pullSlot` method inf your `actionPerformed`. Something like this

```
public interface PullInterface {
    public void pullSlot();
}

public class GGCGuiLotto implements PullInterface {
    ArrayList<ImageIcon> slotList = new ArrayList<>();  // global scope.
    JLabel aReel1lbl = new JLabel();
    JLabel bReel2lbl = new JLabel();
    JLabel cReel3lbl = new JLabel();
    Random rand = new Random();

    public GGCGuiLotto() {
        GenPLCListener listener = new GenPLCListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void pullSlot() {
        // do what you need to do here to implement a pulling of the lever
        int r1 = rand.nextInt(slotList.size());
        int r2 = rand.nextInt(slotList.size());
        int r3 = rand.nextInt(slotList.size());

        reel1lbl.setIcon(slotList.get(r1));
    }
}

public class GenPLCListener implement ActionListener {
    private PullInterface pull;

    public GenPLCListener(PullInterface pull) {
        this.pull = pull;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pull.pullSlot();
    }
}
```

Comment: What I would like to do is that when the button is pressed it generates random number from the array list into the  aReel1lbl.setIcon(slotlist.get(plc1));. As if it is a slot machine. So each time you click the button 3 new images appear in plc1 2 and 3 locations.

Comment: You can just have a `pullReel` method in your `GGCGuiLotto` class that will do the shuffling. Then in the listener just call `lotto.pullReel`.  It seems the complete answer is out of the scope of your posted question. But this is how to access other instance variables.  What I suggest is for you to trying and work out the `pullReel` method, and if you get stuck, post another question here.

Comment: I have it set up as it is here and it seems to be working. The only part that remains is the pullSlot method(). not sure how to implement it so it generates a new set of images from the array into the place holders in the labels.

Comment: You seems to already know how to do it, since you got it to work the first time. You got three random numbers (which should actually be `nextInt(7)` since you have 7 images), and you set the icon to the labels. Do the exact same thing in the method. The problem you may be having is scoping. I don't know how you have declared all your variables, but if they are declared in the constructor, then they are locally scoped and cannot be accessed elsewhere. So you need to give them a global scope (declare them _outside_ of the constructor), so they can be accessed from the method. See edit od edit

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Got a 100% on the project.