# Java: Remove an active key listener that's in another class

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm making a little game that draws "Game over" at a certain event and I want the player to lose control of the character when this happens. I am using key adapter in a different class and adding it in the constructor, like this:

```
addKeyListener(new GetKeyStroke(this));
```

My game over code looks like this (it's in the paint method):

```
if (gameOver) {
        g.setFont(pauseFont);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("Game Over!", screenSize.width / 2 - 110, screenSize.height / 5);  
    }
```

I've tried using

```
removeKeyListener(new GetKeyStroke(this));
```

but from what I know, that creates a new object and that's why it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Off topic but look into using [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing apps. Often you'll face focus issues with `KeyListener`. Key Bindings are actually recommended by Oracle over the use of `KeyListener` for particular key reactions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some kind of reference variable for the `GetKeyStroke` you add.

```
private GetKeyStroke keyListener = new GetKeyStroke(this);
...
addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

You may also want to have a `getter` for it, if you want to access it from another class, say something like

```
public class One {
    private GetKeyStroke keyListener;

    public One() {
        keyListener = new GetKeyStroke(this);
        addKeyListener(keyListener);
    }

    public GetKeyStroke getKeyListener(){
        return keyListener;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass the `One` as reference to `Two` and use the `getKeyListener` method to get a reference to the same instance `GetKeyStoke`

```
public class Two {
    private One one;
    private GetKeyStroke keyListener;

    public Two( final One one ) {
        this.one = one;
        keyListener = one.getKeyListener();
    }

    public someMehod() {
        one.removeKeyListener(keyListener);
    }
}
```

---

Maybe more proper designs would be make use of an `interface`. An example can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206175/2587435) and maybe even a more advanced topic of [MVC Design](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html) may be of future interest to you.

---

**Side Note:**

- As noted in my comment to your original post: Look into using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing apps. Often you'll face focus issues with `KeyListener`. Key Bindings are actually recommended by Oracle over the use of `KeyListener` for particular key reactions.

Comment: I'm a day late and a dollar short 1+

Answer (score -1):

u could create a object as your keylistener

```
Object a = new GetKeyStroke();
```

then you can add and remove it.

```
button.addKeyListener((KeyListener) a);
button.removeKeyListener((KeyListener) a);
```

**Note** i am not a expert, i know using Object isnt good, but i just could not figure out what i was supposed to use