# JFrame, JPanel, JButton, and Inheritance

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

So, I made a `JFrame` class and a `JPanel` class (which is pretty complicated beacuse there are some buttons in this panel). In this `JFrame` class, I have to make an array of the `JPanel` class, so it goes like this

```
public class frame extends JFrame
{
    //SOME VARIABLES AND METHODS HERE
    int lines;

    public frame()
    {
        //SOME CODE HERE
        panelWithButton[] pwb = new panelWithButton[5];
        //SOME CODE HERE
    }
}
```

And the problem is, the buttons in this `JPanel` have different `ActionListeners` for each button where it should change the variables in that `JFrame` class

```
public class panelWithButton extends JPanel
{
    //SOME VARIABLES AND METHOD
    Jbutton aButton = new JButton();
    Jbutton bButton = new JButton();
    Jbutton cButton = new JButton();

    public button()
    {
        //SOME CODE HERE
        add(aButton);
        aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
                frame.lines = 4;
            }
        });

        add(bButton);
        aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
                frame.lines = 5;
            }
        });

        add(cButton);
        aButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
                frame.lines = 6;
            }
        });
        //SOME CODE HERE
     }
}
```

So, that's it. Each button will change the variable of the frame differently. But it's not working. I think the problem is with this code, but I don't know what should I change it to:

```
frame.lines
```

Here is the error: `non-static variable lines cannot be referenced from a static context.`

Please help me. Sorry for my broken English and if my question is not clear enough, just ask. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I would have a `public Action[] getActions()` method in the frame class (or better still, a class that extends `Object` with a `public JFrame getFrame()` method), then iterate the `Action` array and add each to a `JToolBar`.  Generally though:  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). And please use meaningful names. E.G. `aButton`, `bButton`, `cButton` -> `exitButton`, `maximizeButton`, `restoreButton`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Here is the error: `non-static variable lines cannot be referenced from a static context`."

You're getting this error because you're trying to access the `lines` in a static way, when `lines` isn't a `static` variable, it's an instance variable. So what to you want to do is get a reference to that instance variable.

One way is to pass the `frame` reference to the `panelWithButton` through constructor injection, then you can access the instance field `lines`. Something like

```
public class frame extends JFrame {
    private int lines;    // private for encapsulation. getter/setter below
    ...
    panelWithButton panel = new panelWithButton(frame.this);
    ...
    public void setLines(int lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }
}

public class panelWithButton extends JPanel {
    private frame f;

    public panelWithButton(final frame f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public void button() {
        ...
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            f.setLines(5);
        }
    }
}
```

By passing the same instance of `frame` to `panelWithButton`, it's able to access the instance members, like the method `setLines`. I used the private field with the `setter` as to not break the rules of encapsulation.

There are better solutions to this common scenario though. This one is just one simple fix (bu with holes). This method exposes the `frame` class unnecesarily. What I would do in this particular situation is use some sort of [MVC architecture](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html).  An easier solution would be to use an `interface` as a middleman and have the `frame` implement it (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206175/2587435), but since all you want to do is manipulate data, the MVC design is the best approach.

---

**Side Notes**

- Use Java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's an example of a simple MVC (Model, View, Controller) design, using some of your program ideas. I'll walk you through it.

**Model**  `LinesModel` class. The only property is has is an `int lines`. It has a `setLines` method. The special thing about this method is that it fires a property change event so when ever the method is called, the view can be changed

```
public void setLines(int value) {
    int oldValue = lines;
    lines = value;
    propertySupport.firePropertyChange(LINES_PROPERTY, oldValue, lines);
}
```

**Controller** `PanelWithButtons` class. Then button , when pressed, calls the `setLines` method of the `LinesModel`, which fires the property change and notifies the interested listener.

```
fiveLines.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lineModel.setLines(4);
    }
});
```

**View** `PaintPanel` class. It basically takes the number of lines from the `LinesModel` and paints that number of lines.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int y = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < lineModel.getLines(); i++) {
        g.drawLine(50, y, 200, y);
        y += 20;
    }
}
```

---

Here's the complete running program. You can run through it and try and learn what's going on.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private LinesModel lineModel;
    private PaintPanel paintPanel;
    private PanelWithButtons panelWithButtons;

    public Frame() {
        lineModel = new LinesModel();
        paintPanel = new PaintPanel();
        panelWithButtons = new PanelWithButtons(lineModel);

        lineModel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                String prop = evt.getPropertyName();
                if (LinesModel.LINES_PROPERTY.equals(prop)) {
                    paintPanel.repaint();
                }
            }   
        });

        add(paintPanel);
        add(panelWithButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setTitle("MVC Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int y = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < lineModel.getLines(); i++) {
                g.drawLine(50, y, 200, y);
                y += 20;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new Frame();
            }
        });
    }
}


class PanelWithButtons extends JPanel {

    private final JButton fourLines = new JButton("FOUR");
    private final JButton fiveLines = new JButton("FIVE");
    private LinesModel lineModel;

    public PanelWithButtons(LinesModel lineModel) {
        this.lineModel = lineModel;

        fiveLines.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PanelWithButtons.this.lineModel.setLines(4);
            }
        });

        fourLines.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PanelWithButtons.this.lineModel.setLines(5);
            }
        });

        add(fourLines);
        add(fiveLines);
    }
}

class LinesModel implements Serializable {

    public static final String LINES_PROPERTY = "linesProperty";
    private int lines;

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public LinesModel() {
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public int getLines() {
        return lines;
    }

    public void setLines(int value) {
        int oldValue = lines;
        lines = value;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(LINES_PROPERTY, oldValue, lines);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to simplify my code by changing some variables, but it turned out to make things worse. Your answer isn't what I'm looking for but I do learn some new trick from your answer and my program is working now thanks to you. Oh, and thanks for some of your notes and advices. I think you're better than my lecturer. Thanks!!