# Drawing Enlarged Images

Tags: java, image-scaling

I am currently doing a project that requires me to draw a large number (100+) images on the screen. The original resolution of each image is 20*20 and I am scaling them to 80*80 with nearest neighbor before drawing them.

I currently use AffineTransform to scale them up when the program is initialized, and redraw the enlarged images every frame in different positions.

Seeing as the target framerate is about 60 fps, I need to find a way to draw them faster, preferably so that it doesn't render them as 80*80 bitmaps. I tried Graphics2D's drawImage method with the width and height parameters, but it actually slowed my program down.

In pseudocode:

```
Image image; //loaded from 20*20 png file

public void init(){
    image = resize(image, 80, 80);
}

public void repaint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I also tried:

```
Image image;

public void repaint(Graphics g){
    ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 80, 80, null);
}
```

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: Cache all the scaled images **once**, then draw those images

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question about that: [Load and Resize Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161326/load-and-resize-image)

Here is my answer: [Load and Resize Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161326/load-and-resize-image/24166016#24166016)

I hope I could help.