# Render Multiple Data Types in a single jTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I want to display a graphic e.g. gif resource and a currency number in a single jtable cell.
below is the code for he cell renderer ,it displays the currency as expected but the graphic is distorted in the cell. Any suggestion

```
 public class CurrencyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

     private final ImageIcon cediImage =
         new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("/resources/images/cedi.gif"));


     public CurrencyCellRenderer() {
         super();
         setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT); 
     }

     @Override
     public void setValue(Object value) {
         if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number)) {
             Number numberValue = (Number) value;
             NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("ghs" ,"GH")); 
             value = formatter.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
         }
         super.setIcon(cediImage);
         super.setValue(value);
     }  

}
```

below is the code attaching the cellrenderer to the table

```
    jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class , new CurrencyCellRenderer());
```

thank you all.

Comment: For better help sooner please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I mean a **full** code but **simple** enough that we can copy-paste it and see the issue you see. Delete unnecesary code such as format like colors, images, etc (if the issue isn't related to them). Good Luck

Comment: Check the size of your icon image.  The following article might also contain some helpful information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size

Comment: How to you mean distorted?

Comment: In your [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).