# How to place an array of JPanels into JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing

When I placed an array into `mainJpanel` it works correctly. I want to place an array into `JScrollPane` but it does not work. Please explain why.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    public  Window() {
        setLocation( 100,100);
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("FontView");
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout( new FlowLayout());
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        setContentPane(mainPanel);

        Method fontMassive = new Method();

        //поехали
        JPanel[] jPanels = new JPanel[3];
        JLabel[] jLabels = new JLabel[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            jPanels[i]=new JPanel();
            jLabels[i] = new JLabel(fontMassive.getFonts(i));
            jPanels[i].add(jLabels[i]);
        }
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            scroll.add(jPanels[i]);
        }
        mainPanel.add(scroll);
    }
}
```

[placed into mainPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrezg.png)

[placed into scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8AgQ.png)

Comment: You could add one jpanel with a  suitable layout to the jscrollpane. And then add all the jpanels to that jpanel.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203037/230513) adds a new `JPanel` having `GridLayout`.

Comment: **Other tips:** 1) `setVisible(true);` This should be last. After all components are added, and immediately after calling `pack()`. 2) `Method` What is that? Post a [mre]. 3) `Window` use descriptive names for classes (methods and attributes). It will help you later, and everyone else right now.  4) Depending on what `Method` is, or does, it might be better here to put a `JList` in the scroll pane and add new information directly to the list component.

Answer (score 0):

Just another Java programmer 's answer was right, i need to place an array into Panel and then place it into Srcoll. 
Thank you guys for the answers.

Comment: One of the purposes of this Web site is for other people, with the same problem, to benefit from your solution. I think you should [edit] your answer and post your updated code that resolved your problem. Alternatively, delete this answer and simply post it as a comment to your question.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.