# Some Image couldn't draw immediately

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I'm new in Java GUI Programming. The following code is the problem which I simplified that.

Two image is drawn when clicked Panel. One is Red Box which is drawn using `drawVrImage()` method, another is Red Star which is drawn using `drawRealImage()` method. Two of all image is drawn along increasing row.

#### Here is result Image:

[image]

It shows after clicked 5 times. but the problem is `drawRealImage()` draws their image just 4 times even though it is called 5 times. Where is first Red Box? Why `BufferedImage` can't show the First Red Box.

`GUI` class just used for load image. All images is loaded and put `HashMap` when it starts. So, I think image loading(`Qwirkle.getImage()`) is not problem. I think that buffered image doesn't have Image Observer is problem. But If It is really problem. How can I draw Second Red Box.

For your information. Here is code explanation. Class `BIsource` has one `BuffedImage`. when I clicked the `UserPanel`. `BufferedImage` in `BIsource` gets its graphics and draw Image. after finished draws image, `UserPanel` gets that image from BIsource. and called `reapint()` method. `paintCompent()` method in `UserPanel` only works for drawing buffered image from BIsource Instance.

How can I solve this Problem?

UserPanel Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UserPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private BIsource draw;
    private BufferedImage bi;
    
    public UserPanel() {

        this.draw = new BIsource();
        this.bi = draw.getBI();
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.draw.drawVrImage();
        this.draw.drawRealImage();
        this.draw.incIndex();
        bi = this.draw.getBI();
        this.repaint();
    }

    class BIsource {

        private BufferedImage biCanvas;

        private HashMap<String, BufferedImage> imageMap;

        private int index = 0;

        public BIsource() {

            // biCanvas Declaration
            biCanvas = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
            Graphics g = biCanvas.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            g.dispose();

            imageMap = new HashMap<>();
            this.createVrImage();
        }

        private void createVrImage() {
            BufferedImage vrImage = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
            Graphics g = vrImage.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 48);
            g.dispose();

            this.imageMap.put("TEST IMAGE", vrImage);
        }

        public BufferedImage getBI() {
            return this.biCanvas;
        }

        public void drawVrImage() {
            Graphics g = biCanvas.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(this.imageMap.get("TEST IMAGE"), 0, index * 50, null);
            g.dispose();
        }

        public void drawRealImage() {
            Graphics g = biCanvas.getGraphics();
            g.drawImage(Qwirkle.getImage("RED STAR"), 200, index * 50, null);
            g.dispose();
        }

        public void incIndex() {
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Qwirkle.loadQwirkleImage();

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainFrame.setLocation(800, 400);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        UserPanel userPanel = new UserPanel();
        mainFrame.add(userPanel);
        userPanel.setSize(500, 500);
        userPanel.setVisible(true);

    }
    

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

Qwirkle Class

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class Qwirkle implements Serializable {

    private static HashMap<String, Image> qwirkleImages;

    // static initialize
    static {

    }

    public enum Color {
        CYAN, GREEN, ORANGE, PURPLE, RED, YELLOW
    }

    public enum Shape {
        CIRCLE, CLOVER, DIAMOND, RECTANGLE, STAR, URCHIN
    }

    private final Color color;
    private final Shape shape;
    private final int index;

    public Qwirkle(Color color, Shape shape, int index) {

        this.color = color;
        this.shape = shape;
        this.index = index;
    }

    public static void loadQwirkleImage() {

        if (Qwirkle.qwirkleImages == null) {
            Qwirkle.qwirkleImages = new HashMap<>();
                String key;
                try {
                    for (Qwirkle.Color color : Qwirkle.Color.values()) {
                        for (Qwirkle.Shape shape : Qwirkle.Shape.values()) {
                            key = new String(color.toString() + " " + shape.toString());
                            Qwirkle.qwirkleImages.put(key, GUI.loadImage(key + ".jpg"));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Already Loading all Qwirkle Image");
        }
    }

    public static Image getImage(String key) {
        return qwirkleImages.get(key);
    }

    synchronized public String getKey() {
        return new String(color.toString() + " " + shape.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new String(color.toString() + " " + shape.toString() + " " + index);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: If debugging isn't immediately helpful, create a [mcve] the focuses on just the problem. In your example, access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: your program without qwirkle and just another image works fine - I advise you against using static; remove all static (and synchronized unless you really KNOW you need it (not just for fun)

Comment: @gpasch Here is fixed code. I wish You know about it is not homework and assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got answer. I changed HashMap Object. I used HashMap for put Image Class. But now I stored BufferedImage at HashMap. It works well. When I clicked first time, it draws one Red Star immediately. then I read about difference between Image and BufferedImage. But I don't have no idea why Image doesn't work well and BufferedImage works well.(Could you expain that? please)

> `private HashMap<String, Image> qwirkleImages;`

is changed to

> `private HashMap<String, BufferedImage> qwirkleImages;`

Here is fixed code. and Here is [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yywzT.png)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UserPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private BIsource draw;
    private BufferedImage bi;

    public UserPanel() {

        this.draw = new BIsource();
        this.bi = draw.getBI();
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.draw.drawVrImage();
        this.draw.drawRealImage();
        this.draw.incIndex();
        bi = this.draw.getBI();
        this.repaint();
    }

    class BIsource {

        private BufferedImage biCanvas;
//      private HashMap<String, Image> qwirkleImages;
        private HashMap<String, BufferedImage> qwirkleImages;
        private HashMap<String, BufferedImage> imageMap;

        private int index = 0;

        public BIsource() {
            this.qwirkleImages = new HashMap<>();
            this.loadAllImage();

            // biCanvas Declaration
            biCanvas = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
            Graphics g = biCanvas.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            g.dispose();

            imageMap = new HashMap<>();
            this.createVrImage();
        }

        public void loadAllImage() {
            String key;
            try {
                for (Qwirkle.Color color : Qwirkle.Color.values()) {
                    for (Qwirkle.Shape shape : Qwirkle.Shape.values()) {
                        key = new String(color.toString() + " " + shape.toString());
                        qwirkleImages.put(key, GUI.loadImage2(key + ".jpg"));
                        System.out.println(key);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void createVrImage() {
            BufferedImage vrImage = new BufferedImage(50, 50, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
            Graphics g = vrImage.createGraphics();
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 48);
            g.dispose();

            this.imageMap.put("TEST IMAGE", vrImage);
        }

        public BufferedImage getBI() {
            return this.biCanvas;
        }

        public void drawVrImage() {
            Graphics g = biCanvas.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(this.imageMap.get("TEST IMAGE"), 0, index * 50, null);
            g.dispose();
        }

        public void drawRealImage() {
            Graphics g = biCanvas.getGraphics();
            Image image = this.qwirkleImages.get("RED STAR");
            if (image == null) {
                System.out.println("image is null");
            }
            g.drawImage(image, 200, index * 50, null);
            System.out.println("DRAW Real");
            g.dispose();
        }

        public void incIndex() {
            index += 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("load all images");
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);
        mainFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setBackground(Color.black);
        mainFrame.setLocation(800, 400);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        UserPanel userPanel = new UserPanel();
        mainFrame.add(userPanel);
        userPanel.setSize(500, 500);
        userPanel.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```