# Java - setLocation/Bounds on a JLabel with an ImageIcon don't work from another Class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

it's my first question so give me critics if i can do anything better.

When i call `Hero.Move.MoveLeft();` the `JLabel` "`labelHero`" don't move visually. But the debugger says that `posX` changes.
The interesting thing is that if i call `Hero.Move.MoveLeft();` before the gamePanel is added the first time to the Frame, than it works. (I have marked the position in the middle of `myWindow`.)

Thx for help guys.

```
package com.company.Game;

import com.company.Characters.Hero;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Hero.Initialize();
        myWindow myWindow = new myWindow();
        PaintObjects.PaintNew();
        myWindow.Repaint();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
        Hero.Move.MoveLeft();
    }
}
```

-

```
package com.company.Characters;

import com.company.Game.Environment;
import com.company.Game.PaintObjects;
import com.company.Game.myWindow;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Hero
{
    public Hero()
    {
        Initialize();
        CreateHeroImg();
    }

public static JLabel labelHero;
public static ImageIcon iconHero = new ImageIcon("/Users/MJulich/IdeaProjects/Spiel mit Gui/src/Imports/Hero.png");

    public static class Life extends Hero
    {
        public static int actual;
        public static int max;
    }

    public static class Mana extends Hero
    {
        public static int actual;
        public static int max;
    }

    public static class Damage extends Hero
    {
        public static int actual;
    }

    public static class Move extends Hero
    {
        public static int width;
        public static int height;
        public static int speed;
        public static int posX;

        public static void MoveLeft()
        {
            if (Move.posX > Environment.posShop){
                Move.posX--;
                PaintObjects.MoveHero();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Life.actual = 10;
        Life.max = 10;
        Mana.actual = 5;
        Mana.max = 5;
        Damage.actual = 1;
        Move.width = 1;
        Move.height = 3;
        Move.speed = 1;
        Move.posX = 10;
    }

    public static void CreateHeroImg()
    {
        iconHero.setImage(iconHero.getImage().getScaledInstance(Move.width*myWindow.scale,Move.height*myWindow.scale, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        labelHero = new JLabel(iconHero);
        labelHero.setBackground(Color.red);
        labelHero.setOpaque(true);
        labelHero.setBounds(Move.width*myWindow.scale*(Move.posX-1),myWindow.heightLabelBackground-Move.height*myWindow.scale+myWindow.offsetPlayerY,Move.width*myWindow.scale,Move.height*myWindow.scale);
        myWindow.gamePanel.add(labelHero);
    }
}
```

-

```
package com.company.Game;

import com.company.Characters.Hero;

public class PaintObjects
{
    public static void PaintNew()
    {
        Hero.CreateHeroImg();
    }
    public static void MoveHero()
    {
        Hero.labelHero.setLocation(Hero.Move.width*myWindow.scale*(Hero.Move.posX-1),myWindow.heightLabelBackground-Hero.Move.height*myWindow.scale+myWindow.offsetPlayerY);

    }
}
```

-

```
package com.company.Game;

public class Environment
{
    public static int posShop = 7;
    public static int posSpawn = 40;
}
```

-

```
package com.company.Game;


import com.company.Characters.Hero;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class myWindow
{
    public static int scale = 20;

    public static JFrame meinFrame;
    public static int heightMeinFrame = 800;
    public static int heightGamePanel = 500;
    public static int heightControlePanel = 300;
    public static int heightLabelBackground = heightGamePanel;
    public static int widthMeinFrame = 1000;
    public static int widthGamePanel = 1000;
    public static int widthControlePanel = 1000;
    public static int widthLabelBackground = widthGamePanel;

    public static int offsetPlayerY = -(5*scale);

    public static JPanel gamePanel;
    public static JPanel controlePanel;
    public static JLabel labelBackground;
    static ImageIcon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon("/Users/MJulich/IdeaProjects/Spiel mit Gui/src/Imports/Background.png");
    static JProgressBar myProgBar1;
    static JButton myJBtn1;
    static JButton myJBtn2;
    static JButton myJBtn3;
    static JButton myJBtn4;
    static JButton myJBtn5;
    static JButton myJBtn6;
    static JButton myJBtn7;
    static JButton myJBtn8;

    public myWindow()
    {
        //create Frame
        meinFrame = new JFrame("Mein JFrame Beispiel");
        meinFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        /* Wir setzen die Breite unseres Fensters auf 1000 Pixel
        und die Höhe unseres Fensters auf 800 Pixel */
        meinFrame.setSize(widthMeinFrame, heightMeinFrame);
        meinFrame.setResizable(false);

            //create gamePanel
            gamePanel = new JPanel();
            gamePanel.setLayout(null);
            gamePanel.setBounds(0, 0, widthGamePanel, heightGamePanel);

                //create Background
                backgroundIcon.setImage(backgroundIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(widthLabelBackground, heightLabelBackground, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
                labelBackground = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
                labelBackground.setOpaque(true);
                labelBackground.setBounds(0,0,widthLabelBackground,heightLabelBackground);
                PaintObjects.PaintNew();

                ***call "Hero.Move.MoveLeft();" here and it works***

                gamePanel.add(labelBackground);


            //create controlePanel
            controlePanel = new JPanel();
            controlePanel.setLayout(null);
            controlePanel.setBounds(0, heightGamePanel+1, widthControlePanel, heightControlePanel);
            controlePanel.setBackground(new Color(200,200,255));

                //create Buttons
                myJBtn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
                myJBtn1.setBounds(25, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
                myJBtn2.setBounds(275, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn3 = new JButton("Button 3");
                myJBtn3.setBounds(525, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn4 = new JButton("Button 4");
                myJBtn4.setBounds(775, 526, 200, 50);
                myJBtn5 = new JButton("Button 5");
                myJBtn5.setBounds(25, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn6 = new JButton("Button 6");
                myJBtn6.setBounds(275, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn7 = new JButton("Button 7");
                myJBtn7.setBounds(525, 601, 200, 50);
                myJBtn8 = new JButton("Button 8");
                myJBtn8.setBounds(775, 601, 200, 50);

                //create Progressbar
                myProgBar1 = new JProgressBar(0, Hero.Life.max);
                myProgBar1.setBounds(25, 676, 200, 50);
                myProgBar1.setStringPainted(true);
                /**einfärben funktioniert noch nicht*/
                /*myProgBar1.setBackground(Color.orange);
                myProgBar1.setForeground(Color.red);*/
                myProgBar1.setString(String.valueOf(Hero.Life.actual) + "/" + String.valueOf(Hero.Life.max));
                myProgBar1.setValue(Hero.Life.actual);

                //add Buttons and Progressbar to controlePanel
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn1);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn2);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn3);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn4);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn5);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn6);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn7);
                controlePanel.add(myJBtn8);
                controlePanel.add(myProgBar1);

            //add Panels to Frame
            meinFrame.add(gamePanel);
            meinFrame.add(controlePanel);

        //show Frame
        meinFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void Repaint()
    {
        myProgBar1.setValue(Hero.Life.actual);
        myProgBar1.setString(String.valueOf(Hero.Life.actual) + "/" + String.valueOf(Hero.Life.max));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a _single_ [mcve] that focuses on the stated problem; you can access posted images via `URL`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513); use synthetic images as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15982915/230513); or use `UIManager` icons, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12228640/230513).

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask high quality questions in future that others can easily answer. For now, please see `trashgod`'s comment and make adjustments to this question accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: Way too many static variables. "static" is not needed. Also you should NOT be using a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx guys,

I have found the problem.

`PaintObjects.PaintNew();` was called two times. One time in the main method and one time in the myWindow constructor. How ever the program lost the connection to the visible object.