# How to create something similar to JFileChooser in Java?

Tags: java, listview, jpanel, filechooser, jtogglebutton

I am trying to make a frame similar to a JFileChooser. I have a scrollpane and 2 toggle buttons, one for list view, and other for icons view. I will be using CardLayout on the scrollpane. However, I don't know where to begin. I would like to know a good approach on this matter. How do I design the 2 panels that will be put over the scrollpane?
Something similar is the GroupBox in C# forms.

Comment: Not quite, I need to know how to create custom views. For example, for the listView option, I will be able to create a Jlist(i think) that will be spread out horizontally on multiple columns. For iconsView i will have some thumbnails that will be displayed vretically on multiple rows, etc.

Comment: My question was very confusing, i know, but you, sir, managed to show me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  I deleted the earlier comments and combined them into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui) for some tips.

> I need to know how to create custom views. For example, for the listView option, I will be able to create a Jlist(i think) that will be spread out horizontally on multiple columns. For iconsView i will have some thumbnails that will be displayed vretically on multiple rows, etc.

For the detail view I'd tend to use a `JTable`. 'horizontally in multiple columns' can be done using a list and [`setLayoutOrientation(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setLayoutOrientation%28int%29).

Comment: +1 for `FileBrowser`! Simple `JTable` and `JList` examples maybe found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7620579/230513).

Comment: Good answers.  Thanks for bringing them to my attention.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create "something similar to JFileChooser" why not to take a look on code of `JFileChooser` itself? You can find JDK source in file `src.zip` under your JDK directory.