# Can I get multiple rows in JPanel with FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, flowlayout

I need solution similar to `GridLayout` but without resizing components in `JPanel`.

Everything works great with `JFrame`, but I need to put those components into `JPanel` instead `JFrame`.

Comment: *"Everything works great with JFrame, but i need to put those components into JPanel instead JFrame"*  Since a frame and panel might have the same layout manager, I do not see the relevance of that statement.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've seen two approaches that may suit your requirement:

- Nest each component in a `JPanel` having `FlowLayout`, which respects the component's preferred size, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3420431/230513).
- Use the `HORIZONTAL_WRAP` or `VERTICAL_WRAP` orientation of `JList`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513).

Answer (score 2):

The following link might help you to choose the most appropriate layout for your needs. Its the Java Tutorial called "A Visual Guide to Layout Manager", which shows nice pictures of each layout and what they look like...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Otherwise, if you say `GridLayout` is similar to what you need, you could always write your own `MyGridLayout` class (that extends `GridLayout`) and overwrite the method that does the autoresizing.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question myself and even though I think using z JList might be a good solution, there's an even simpler way of doing it with a customized FLowLayout, called WrapLayout, available here: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/

I ended up using it in my project and it works very well. The only issue I run into is when I set my window to the full screen mode the layout did not update correctly. I used a simple workaround, which was this:

```
        //int targetWidth = target.getSize().width;
        int targetWidth = target.getParent().getSize().width; // FIXME: this is a hack for getting the correct size when switching between full screen modes on Mac
```

With that small hack it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just Override preferredLayoutSize() in flowlayout and set Maximum size to it. set Alignment as LEADING and set it to your JPanel. You'll get what you want

```
private FlowLayout getFlowLayout(int maximumSize)
      {
        if (flowLayout == null)
        {
          flowLayout = new FlowLayout()
          {
            @Override 
            public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target)
            {
              Dimension dimension = super.preferredLayoutSize(target);
              dimension.width = Math.min(maximumSize, dimension.width);
              return dimension;
            }
          };
          flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEADING);
        }
        return flowLayout;
      }
```

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't work - won't give you a multi row FlowLayout.

Comment: Also there's a typo in the code - you're putting width where height should be used, but even with this fixed, it hardly makes any sense to try to do the rest of it as it won't fix the issue.

Comment: @b005t3r "Also there's a typo in the code - you're putting width where height should be used"
can you point out where I use width instead of height?