# JFreeChart combinedDomainXYPlot - maintaining order of plots

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to hide/show plots in combinedDomainXYPlot but the class only allows to add/remove plots. For instance, if I have 3 plots, I remove the second, and then add it, visually it is going to add it as the third chart at the bottom. Is there any way to maintain the charts order visually?

Comment: What happens when you remove them all and add the desired ones back in order?

Comment: That is what I was thinking about but I need to make sure the ordering is right using a separate collection...

Comment: I'd build the display list while looping through the selection model; I was curious if the display effect was acceptable.

Comment: I dont quite get that trashgod. Could you elaborate? You want to iterate through the selection mofel i.e. my own construct, and tthen based onn the selectiion add and remove to the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `ListSelectionModel`, which is available to both `JList`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513), and `JTable`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620693/230513). The former has a flexible layout, while the latter has a convenient `JCheckbox` [renderer/editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Lets assume your model ultimately produces a `List<Plot>` named `selected`. You can loop though the `getSubplots()` list to `remove()` all current plots, then loop through your `List<Plot>` to `add()` each selected plot back.

Addendum: If the subplots are otherwise identical, you may be able to to `add()` or `remove()` a minimum number of subplots and replace the models of those that remain using `setDataset()`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). It's slightly more complicated but perhaps less visually disruptive.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use `AbstractRenderer.setSeriesVisible` depending on the `Renderer` you are using.

This hides rather than removes the series so order is unaffected.  If you have access to the JFreeChart demo check out HideSeriesDemo1 for an example.