# TableModel - modify external objects upon setting a value

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I have a separate class that implements a TableModel interface used for JTable. I have one Boolean column, presented as a column of checkboxes and I was wondering how I can inform an external object that certain values need to be updated? If I had this implementation as a nested class, I could access the members of the main class from within, but if I decided to move it to a separate class, do I need to register my main class as a listener on the Table model implementation and then raise an event?

Comment: It seems your question already contains the answer. Yes, you should register your main class as a listener on the TableModel, and then raise an event when one of the values is updated.

Comment: from external classes to the JTableM Model??? or from JTable Model out ...???

Comment: I was thinking about subscribing to tableModel events

Comment: @mKorbel: This [view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11921532/230513) may be the one intended to listen to the `TableModel`. +1 for preferring loose coupling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on @gontard's correct answer, you can arrange for your *view* (say a [`CombinedDomainXYPlot`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11904583/230513)) to listen to your `TableModel`. Both [known subclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) include the required `addTableModelListener()` implementation. Your *view* can then react accordingly when it sees the change.

Answer (score 3):

Your external object should listen directly to the model value change. There is no need to add a dependency on the view.