# Inserting an Image into a JList

Tags: java, image, swing, list

I am trying to load an `Image` into a `List` but I can't seem to get it to work. I have tried

```
ImageIcon pic = new ImageIcon("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/68X8RUxeXeA/default.jpg");
JLabel picLbl = new JLabel(pic);

Object[] lol = {picLbl, "pic", "length"};
list = new JList(lol);
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

That just puts `javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/68X8RUxeXeA/default.jpg,disabledIcon=,horizontalAlignment=CENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,verticalTextPosition=CENTER]`

Instead of the actual picture. I have looked around for a while but can't seem to find anything that works. If any of you guys know how to achieve this, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`DefaultListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html) is a `JLabel`, so you can use `setIcon()` with an `ImageIcon`. This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) may be a useful starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Jlabels cannot be displayed by JList. Create an ImageIcon from your Image and use that for your array of elements.

If you want to know more about how a JList actually displays elements, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer

Comment: I already looked at that but I can't seem to get that to work. They didn't make it very easy to understand.

Comment: What will happen if you use ImageIcon instead of JLabel?

Comment: @JakubZaverka: A `DefaultListCellRenderer` _is_ a `JLabel`; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12448037/230513).

Comment: @thrashgod yes thats correct. But this was a case where JLabels were actually the elements in the list. Though it may seem strange, DefaultListCellRenderer doesn't know how to display JLabels.

Comment: @JakubZaverka: D'oh, you're right; thanks for clarifying. The default [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) "displays the object's string value."