# Java JCombobox coloring of selected item not updated until focus lost

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I have a difficult problem with this code:

```
public class StatusAndPersonPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel myPanel;
    private String[] status = {"Good", "Bad", "Not so bad"};
    private Color[] backgrounds = {Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.ORANGE};
    private JComboBox<String> box;

    public ComboboxConstructor() {
        myPanel = new JPanel();
        box = new JComboBox<String>(status);
        ComboBoxRenderer myBackgrounds = new ComboBoxRenderer(box);
        myBackgrounds.setColors(backgrounds);
        myBackgrounds.setStrings(status);

        box.setRenderer(myBackgrounds);
        box.addActionListener(this);

        Color selectedColor = (Color) backgrounds[box.getSelectedIndex()];
        box.setBackground(selectedColor);
        myPanel.add(box); // putting it into my panel
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Color selectedColor = (Color) backgrounds[box.getSelectedIndex()];
        box.setBackground(selectedColor);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the image, in Step 1 all colors are made as I want them,
but now I click on "not as bad" and the `JComboBox` collapses with the right choice, but doesn´t change the color (the arrow does, I don´t know why), until my focus is lost (Step 3, clicking another `JPanel element) the color is given properly.

Now, I know it´s just a little cosmetic problem, but it´s driving me crazy! I tried it with `ActionListener`, `ItemListener` (after change), and `FocusListener` (focus lost and gained), but the result stays always the same as shown in Step 2.

[image]

Thank you so much for your help and thoughts in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) is displayed using a single [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for all cells. You can change the color in your `ListCellRenderer`, as shown in the [`CustomComboBoxDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#eg).

Addendum: Related examples may be found in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7620579/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer... i just had to write 
box.transferFocusUpCycle(); 
in the ActionPerformed method

so he looses the focus an repaints the selected item like in Step 2. 
Thanks for your advice anyways! best Andrea