# I wish to use a selected word from a combo box to highlight that word in a Jtable which contains a wordsearch.

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JTable containg a wordsearch puzzle and a drop down menu below it containing a list of the words contained in the puzzle. I am hoping to find a way to have it so that when a word is selected in the drop down menu it highlight or font changes in the JTable. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well i have figured out how to actually click on a cell in the puzzle and have it highlight but I cant seem to find a method to actually choose a particular cell and change its font/color(eg. table.getCell(1,5)). If I can find a way to do this I should be sorted.

Comment: be sure to read the chapter on how to use JTable in the online tutorial referenced in the [swing tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) - it explains exactly what/how to do it

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) using `JList`, a `ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` permits non-contiguous selections. You can use `addSelectionInterval()` in the `ListSelectionModel` to highlight the letters of your chosen word. You can enhance the display in your implementation of `ListCellRenderer`.

`JTable` uses the same `ListSelectionModel`; it uses a `TableCellRenderer`, rather than a `ListCellRenderer`, but the [concept](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is the same.

As a word search puzzle need not be editable, either `JTable` or `JList` may be a suitable view.

[image]