# Chat Client emoticons window JAVA

Tags: java, swing, popup, window, panel

I've been working on creating a chat client(java swing) and I've just made my emoticons fully useable but other than having users type ":)" for example, I want to provide a popup window with all the available emoticons. What I'm searching for is a way to make such a window( for example like Skype's). How and with what can I go about it? I've tried with a JMenu, but it doesn't do what I want. I want to put a small image(probably emoticon) near the enter text area and when it's clicked, a square filled with emoticons pops up and on mouse click for example ":)" is entered in the text area.

Comment: Your question needs to be a little more specific.  What exactly do you mean by 'popup window' as opposed to a normal JFrame?  What have you tried so far and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: @Martin what logic did you used for placing emoticons in your chat window?? I am having some problem with Implementation any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean a chat window like this sort. In that case, you'll need to learn how to layer components over one another, in this case a jPanel, or a jLayeredPane nested inside the main jFrame.

[image: Chat]

Answer (score 3):

This [`ListPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) might be a useful, as the `DefaultListCellRenderer` can display an `Icon`.

[image]

```
Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("html.pendingImage");
...
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object
    value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    JLabel label =  (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(
        list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(N, N, N, N));
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    return label;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more information, I assume that what you are really after is a window which appears without window decorations (i.e. borders and title bar) and which does not show in the task bar.  I therefore suggest you look at the [JWindow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) documentation, which does exactly this.