# Getting label icon to appear above text

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to get the `JLabel` icon to appear above the text for the label.

Currently I have the following code;

```
URL loc = null;
        ImageIcon img = null;
        JLabel label = null;

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        loc = Test.class.getResource("/Images/imageName.jpg");
        img = new ImageIcon(loc);
        label = new JLabel("someText", img, JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setIconTextGap(0);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.RIGHT);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
```

The output I currently see is the label text to the right of the image icon. Can anyone suggest what to change?

Comment: do you want to put Icon to JLabel, and under Icon (in the JLabel) should be placed describtion

Comment: label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

You need to center align on the horizontal axis for the text to appear under the icon.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Icon with text beneath]

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TopLabel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Text");

                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                        32,32,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));

                label.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
                label.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants "Text", say yellow color, to be inside black square.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov  If that turns out to be the case, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Ok, the question is not clear. So if that's the case I suggest him to use `drawString`, not sure if that possible to achieve without it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, and you want to show a text inside (in the middle of) a image/icon then you have 
an option to use [`Graphics.drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) to draw your text inside image.

```
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(url);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2d)img.getGraphics();
g.drawString("Text", x, y); //y > 0
g.dispose();

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bimg));
```