# How to load a JList in horizontal manner?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

How to load a `JList` in horizontal fashion?? Here is my code,I am trying to display the `JList`similar to the screen shot provided.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    private JList toolsList;
    private ArrayList<File> toolXmlList;

    public Test()
    {
    toolXmlList = new ArrayList<File>();
    toolXmlList = loadFiles();

    setVisible(true);
    setSize(300,300);
    setTitle("Test Jlist");
    createComponents();

    }

    public void createComponents()
    {
    toolsList = new JList();
    toolsList.setModel(displayDefaltTools());
    toolsList.setLayoutOrientation(javax.swing.JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(toolsList,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a list model and add the tools to it
     *
     * @return DefaultListModel
     */
    public DefaultListModel displayDefaltTools() {
    DefaultListModel dlistModel = new DefaultListModel();
    String presentation = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < toolXmlList.size(); i++) {
        //System.out.println(idSet.get(i));
        presentation = presentation +  toolXmlList.get(i).getName() ;
        dlistModel.addElement(presentation);
        presentation = "";
    }
    return dlistModel;
    }

    public ArrayList loadFiles()
    {
    ArrayList<File> xmlFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File f = new File(".");
    File [] folList = f.listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<folList.length;i++)
    {
        if(folList[i].getName().startsWith("Tool_Frag"))
        {
            File[] fileList=folList[i].listFiles();
            for(int j=0;j<fileList.length;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(fileList[j].getName());
                xmlFiles.add(fileList[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlFiles;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    new Test();
    }
}
```

I am trying to get a jlist in this manner,items displayed one next to another
[image: screenshot on layout of jlist]

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) showing `HORIZONTAL_WRAP`.

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513) with icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to do two things:

1. Set the `LayoutOrientation` to `JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP` or `JList.VERTICAL_WRAP` as [per the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).
2. Make the list wide enough that it can display more than one element per row. Use `setVisibleRowCount()` for this.

   Calling `setPreferredSize()` also works but can cause trouble when you use layout managers.

Alternatively, consider using a `JTable` if you must make sure a certain number of rows/columns (like all elements in a single line).

Comment: Using `setVisibleRowCount()` will leverage the renderer's preferred size; invoking `setPreferredSize()` is [problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: second bullet is wrong (even if the tutorial spreads such ... crap ;): whatever the problem, setXXSize is _not_ the solution (to at least 2nd approximation). Instead, use a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And is it possible to display different icons in JList without any text??? Just the icons alone.

Comment: @Balaram26: Check the Swing trail for examples how to use a custom list item renderer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i did figure out the way to do it :)