# How to set JList Orientation to horizontal (Netbeans)

Tags: java

I need to make a list of runners that arrive each at a different time. So basically what i want is to show in a Jlist the name of the runner, his team and the time he took to finish the race all in a single row. Is there a method for this?

So far i've only found [list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);] but i'm not sure if i'm using it correctly or if its even a solution to my problem.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you tried already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a JList in horizontal manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967375/how-to-load-a-jlist-in-horizontal-manner)

Comment: Please make sure you search before positing a new question.