# Stepping through JList with up and down keys

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am displaying a JList that contains file names, in a JScrollPane. I want to select files either by clicking on a line, or by using the up and down keys.

Using the mouse works fine, but if I select one line, then click "down" or "up", it skips one entry, and selects the next line but one. I thought maybe the key was bouncing, but there is only one key event per key stroke.

I keep adding traces to the code, but I just can't see my problem!

Do I need to do something with the `ListModel`?  Help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Let's work with real code if possible.

Comment: @PaulMorrison: I've cited a reference implementation below and listed a few things to check.

Comment: by default, up/down keys are bound to moving the selection to the previous/next: nothing to do on your part

Comment: @kleopatra - Of course - that explains everything - thanks a million!  However, thanks also, trashgod - ListSelectionListener was part of the answer as well!  So it's working great now! I will answer my question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to make sure this question is officially answered...  Kleopatra pointed out that up and down keys are handled automatically, which explains why I was skipping entries.  In addition, I added a ListSelectionListener (suggested by trashgod) to add some application-specific logic to the key handling.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 3):

You might compare your approach to this working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) that uses a `ListSelectionListener`. In particular check your use of `getValueIsAdjusting()`. Also verify that you do not interfere with the existing [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), and do not add an unecessary [`KeyListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). This [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513) is pictured below.

[image]