# Select distinct cells from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

I have a `JTable`, and I want to do the following tasks:

1. Select a cell
2. Select a block of cells
3. Select distinct cells

Comment: Have you tried to implement those things so far?

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [*How to Use Tables: User Selections*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection), `JTable` supports multiple selections among *rows* , but not among individual *cells*. You may be able to achieve the desired effect using `JList` using `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` and `HORIZONTAL_WRAP`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620726/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513).

[image]