# cannot add different mouse event listeners to different panels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, event-listener

**Introduction:**

I am trying to show all files in a folder in a grid view, when clicked on the file, I should print out that name on the command line.

I have jpanels for all the files, so I am trying to detect click on the jpanel and assign action to that panel, in a loop.

**My problem,**

When using the for loop, I have variable "name", which keeps the name of file, I am trying to add mouse listener like this,

```
panel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("MOUSE_RELEASED_EVENT:for "+name);
    }
});
```

As you can notice, I am iterating over `i`, adding mouselisteners to all panels thus, but the problem is the variable name itself is being used in the mouselisteners.

**Example**

If what written above is not the way to explain it, **I mean say I have two files, A and B.**

What I am looking for is, mouse listener for first is,

```
System.out.println("MOUSE_RELEASED_EVENT:for A"); //Since name="A" here.
```

For second file is,

```
System.out.println("MOUSE_RELEASED_EVENT:for B");  //Since name="B" here.
```

**But** it doesn't happen this way, variable name is itself attached to the mouse listeners, and what I get always is the final value of name, in my example "B" always. Since it was the last value of name in the loop.

How do I solve this problem?

As an extra, can someone tell if I can fix size in BorderLayout for child panels, they get resized no matter what I use, `setSize, setPreferredSize, setMaximumSize, setMinimumSize.`

Thanks for time and efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JPanel`'s `setName()/getName()` methods storing the variable there.

Then in the listener just use `((JPanel)event.getSource()).getName();`

Comment: Thanks. +1. Added new code as an answer here for future references, which ofcourse is derived from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, make a `GridLayout` of `JButton` instances, with each button having a suitable [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513). Each `Action` can hold a reference to its own `File`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer, but in a jButton too, wont I use setactionCommand(name), and then the same problem would occur? name will always hold the last value in the loop. And I am still using gridlayout, for all child panels.

Comment: No, each `Action` can see its own `File`

Comment: Okay. Thanks, however the problem solved, any suggestion for the sizing of panel, BorderLayout.CENTER holds the panels, so all are getting resized, if I only have two files, it gives a bad view.:(

Comment: `JList` makes a nice icon view, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754697/230513); also consider `putClientProperty()` if more that a name is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, my final code, as suggested by StanislavL, I first set the name for the `jpanel`,

and then retrieve it when clicked, and works fine.

```
    panel[i].setName(name);
panel[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        System.out.println("MOUSE_RELEASED_EVENT:for "+ ((JPanel)e.getSource()).getName());
    }
});
```