# How to perform multiple cell selection in a jtable with mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple JTable but how can I add cellselection so that when a user left clicks with the mouse, the cell is selected. When the user selects any other cell in any other row, that cell is also selected. If the user left clicks on an already selected cell, that cell gets unselected.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Souciance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, what I have done myself is create an ArrayList to store the selected cells in. Then refer to that array when you need to know which cells are selected. Then I created a custom cell renderer. In that class, I would check if a cell was in the ArrayList of selected cells, and if it was I would set it to the table cell selected color.

```
... public class MyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
...

        //Defined in your class somewhere
        //Add column values to it when clicked on or selected   

        private final Color selectedColumn = Color.YELLOW;
        List<String> selectedCols = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        if (selectedCols.contains(cellValue)) {
            tableCell.setBackground(selectedColumn);
        } else {
            tableCell.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.background"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> When the user selects any other cell in any other row, that selected
>   is selected.

- [this not possible for non_continous cell selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620579/individual-and-not-continuous-jtables-cell-selection), because `ListSelectionMode` is only two dimensional,
- could be possible (never tried that) with `custom Renderer` and `MouseListener`, but then have to add /clone `XxxTableModel` with storing a `selected cell(s)`, model contains only `Boolean value`

Comment: Are there previous open source alternatives that provide this functionality?

Comment: AFAIK not, never saw that, needed that too, have to check [JIDE Software(non_free)](http://www.jidesoft.com/). e.i.

Comment: This [demo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) shows available modes.