# How to read Checkboxes status in Jlist

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jlist, jcheckbox

I am developing a GUI where I have included some Checkboxes into a Jlist but I cannot read their status. Below i have an example of my code

```
final JScrollPane scrollPaneWat = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPaneWat.setBounds(526, 248, 152, 140);
        Pane.add(scrollPaneWat);
        scrollPaneWat.hide();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final JList<?> list = new JList(new CheckListRendererClasses[] {
                new CheckListRendererClasses("a"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("b"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("c"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("d"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("e"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("f"),
                new CheckListRendererClasses("g"),
        scrollPaneWat.setViewportView(list);
        list.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        list.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 14));

        list.setCellRenderer(new CheckListRenderer());
          list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
          list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
                JList list = (JList) event.getSource();
                int index = list.locationToIndex(event.getPoint());
                CheckListRendererClasses item = (CheckListRendererClasses)
                   list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                item.setSelected(! item.isSelected());
                list.repaint(list.getCellBounds(index, index));
             }
          });
```

I have tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    Object sel = list.getModel().getElementAt(i);

    System.out.print(sel.toString());
}
```

and I get back a, b, c, d, e, f, g

Also, when i tried this:

```
System.out.println(list.isSelectedIndex(1));
```

if I tick the Checkbox a, it prints true. But if the Checkbox a is ticked and I tick one more (so now I have ticked the Checkbox a and c) it returns false.

It's like it keeps my last choice.

What I want is, for example if I have ticked the a, c, d Checkboxes to be able to make a for loop and see everytime if a checkbox at value i is ticked or not.

Thank you

Comment: Use JTable instead. Example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: list.repaint(list.getCellBounds(index, index)); talking about CheckListRendererClasses isn't good designated, or usage of is wrong, by default casted value (Boolean) from model must to returns true of false, for String value "true" of "false", otherwise put this class to the trash

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy could be a nice answer (with getColumnClass)

Comment: I think the problem might be with this line: 

   list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); Surely that means only one checkbox can be selected?

Comment: @mKorbel It would be a good idea to develop a table which can edit some checkable options. If I have time this evening, I will try to do it.

Comment: @user3358377 I'm strongly suggest to use [SINGLE_SELECTION](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7620693/714968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION` to `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` to allow more than one selection at a time.