# JList selection, successive items are marked as selected when popup is introduced in-between

Tags: java, swing, focus, selection, jlist

I have a `JList` and `JTextArea` pair. Based on the selected item on `JList`, Data will be displayed in JTextArea. But for some data, user inputs are needed, and are collected by a `JOptionPane`. The problem is when I traverse `JList` with **up** and **down** arrows; having `JOptionPane` popped up; **both successive** items are selected. I mean previously selected data is not getting unselected, but only the last data is supposed to be selected. I am popping `JOptionPane` inside `changeTextArea()` method and the *Code* is as follows. Thanks for any help!

```
private class JListListenerEdit implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
        if (!event.getValueIsAdjusting() && listEdit.isFocusOwner()) {
            Data selection = null;
            try {
                selection = listEdit.getSelectedValue();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (null != selection) {
                changeTextArea(selection);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void changeTextAreaEditData(SData selection) {
        if (selection.requireInputs()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Provide inputs to process the data.","Inputs Required", JOptionPane.INFORMATION);
            this.textAreaEditData.setText(processData(selection.getData()));
        } else {
            this.textAreaEditData.setText(selection.getData());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you are checking `getValueIsAdjusting()` in your `ListSelectionListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177255/230513). You might try wrapping the call to `changeTextArea()` inside an `Runnable` using `invokeLater()`.

Comment: Excellent; I'll add a friendly reminder not to swallow exceptions.

Comment: Events are triggered even before the user has not selected any items. That is when adding list items using model. So I was getting null pointer exception, hence swallowed :D. I know this is not suggested, but what can I do? Thanks again!

Comment: @Ahamed: It may be possible to `addListSelectionListener()` _after_ the `ListModel` is constructed.

Answer (score 1):

why confusing user with this way, use `JPopup` (right `MouseClick`) for `JList`, rather that catch everywhere `last/previous` selected `Item`

Comment: Not all of the Jlist items requires input, only some.

Comment: @Ahamed Then you can add context menu behavior to all `ListItem`s and override that with an empty listener for non-required items.