# How to draw 2 JLabels on each row of a JList?

Tags: java, swing

Let's say I want to have a JList like this:

[image]

For each rows, there are 2 JLabels: the left is is the color name, and the right one is the color itself. How do you write your own custom ListCellRenderer for this purpose?

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to accomplish this? Please post a valid [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

In outline,

- Give your [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) that displays an `Icon`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19092305/230513).
- Use `setHorizontalTextPosition()` and `setVerticalTextPosition()` to achieve the desired layout.
- Use a custom implementation of `Icon`, such as the `ColorIcon` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).